# Centos 6.4 only allow user to bind to certain port?

Tags: linux

How do I configure a CentOS 6.4 server so that certain users can only run servers on certain ports? e.g. if I have a user that is used for running a server and I only want him to be able to bind to port 1036.

Comment: Very interesting thought. Shouldn't this be application specific. What is the name of the application service?

Comment: In this case I am dealing with untrusted users running node servers

Comment: Sounds like a job for SELinux, though it will probably be complicated.

Comment: Could you point me to a guide and/or reference on using SELinux to accomplish this?

Comment: Is it a apache server? If so, we are current set up something like apache listen on port 1036 and user document root is /home/user/public_html. The configuration is using "url port mapping" or something like that, sorry Im mobile and dont have server access atm, I can check exact syntax later if you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you can do this using network namespaces because thats how I did it. But it is pretty complicated.

The process would be this.

1. Create a network namespace by using `unshare`
2. Create a veth device using `ip link add type veth ....`
3. Move one end of the veth into this device using `ip link set vethX netns ${PIDOFUNSHARE}`
4. Bring up loopback (if not already) in the new namespace.
5. Bring up an IP address (if not already) in the new namespace and the `vethX` device.
6. Set a default route in new network namespace to an IP in the parent namespace.
7. Set a static route to the ip you added in the child namespace to go down the `vethX` in the parent namespace.

Now, the untrusted user of course has complete ownership of that IP, but you can use IPtables in the parent namespace to do DNATing to the specific port they are allowed to bind to and restrict communication out to only that port.
Its impossible for the user to effectively deny service on another port for another user as he has a specific IP that works only from within that users namespace.

Note things are more complicated if you use `nslcd` or `nscd` for name resolution service as the unix socket that is used for inter process communication is invalid in the child namespace. The only way I was able to fix this was to patch these programs to provide a TCP transport and do name resolution services in the parent namespace over TCP.

I also wrote a program in C that uses netlink calls to set all the above up. The program is closed source so unfortunately I cannot share it with you.

For the record, doing this in Fedora is a bit easier because you can create named network namespaces in it. But EL6 does not provide the `/proc/<pid>/ns` functionality to do this.